# "Database access" when not connected to the database

Tags: database, offline

I have a small (desktop) application which basically consists of an user-friendly [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) interface to a few tables (and joined tables)

It currently works with a MySQL database but I would like to make it available when there is no connection to the database, most likely because the user has no internet connection.

My first thought was to create a SQLite "buffer" in between the MySQL database and the application, e.g. by executing all queries on the SQLite but also storing them in a log table so that they can be executed later in the main database with very basic conflict resolution (I will basically let the user solve it if a conflict is detected)

Due to the simplicity of the application this shouldn't be too difficult and good exercise, but I think I would be re-inventing the wheel. So my question is: are there existing solutions or other approaches for this problem?

Comment: Have you looked at replication solutions?

Comment: @Marcin those would require the user to install a full-fledged SQL server on its computer, so I'd rather avoid that

Comment: There might be something in simple replication solutions that you could use, though. Googling "heterogenous replication" turns up a bunch of stuff that might be germane, even if not directly a solution.

Comment: Replication is indeed the proper term. I'm going to research some solutions

Comment: @Marcin if you put your comment into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be something in simple replication solutions that you could use.

Googling "heterogenous replication" turns up a bunch of stuff that might be germane, even if not directly a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Please define "offline". Do you mean that

1. the actual database server is shut-down, or
2. just that you are accessing it through a non-web interface?